# How to rebuild ALL?

Tags: visual-studio, rebuild

In Visual Studio, how do I rebuild a complete solution, including all configurations?

If I choose "Rebuild solution", it always rebuilds ONLY Debug or ONLY Release, but never both.

Comment: what version of visual studio are you using?  That will make a difference.

Comment: Just a heads up... Batch Build is only available if you click directly on the solution and not on one of the sub projects or files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the batch build option...right click on the solution to see it.

Here is a screen shot (VS2010 but I believe it's the same for VS2008 too)

[Batch build screen shot http://img368.imageshack.us/img368/1516/batchbuild.jpg](http://img368.imageshack.us/img368/1516/batchbuild.jpg)

Comment: I don't see "Batch Build" - just the Build/Rebuild/Clean options. What choice are you referring to?

Comment: It is in the right click context menu of the solution, not in the property pages. :-)

Comment: I usually find it under the Build menu -- Build -> Batch Build... -- from there, check the configurations you want to build and invoke the build operation.

Comment: I don't have "Batch Build" in either of those locations - my choices seem to mirror what I see in VS2005, which I also have installed. It's not something I need to enable?

Comment: Make sure you right clicking on the solution... it definitely is there for me in VS2005.

Comment: I'll bet that's the case, though I'm MSDN Unlimited (or whatever they're calling it now) and have "Team System" installed, though I don't see this option. I'll have to look into it, though - I've wanted this feature before.

Comment: Interesting - I see that option on my home computer. I could have sworn I installed from the same media (and even the installed info is the same), but they have different SKU numbers...

Comment: Thanks. When I asked this question, I didn't have Batch Build anywhere in my Visual Studio. By now I've discovered the reason was this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460459/visual-studio-configuration-manager-missing

Comment: @Sandeep -- The link to screen shot appears to be broken :-(

Answer (score 1):

Some of my project had the 'batch build' option, others didn't.

Found that those that did have it were written in c#.net and those that didn't have it were in vb.net, more information here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj651644.aspx

You can build most types of projects with multiple, or even all, of their build configurations at the same time by using the Batch Build dialog box.

However, you can't build the following types of projects in multiple build configurations at the same time:

- Windows 8.x Store apps built for Windows using JavaScript.
- All Visual Basic projects.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2005, I discovered that under Build->Configuration Manager, I did not have Build checked for the project.

Comment: have it solved rebuilding situation about ONLY Debug or ONLY Release ?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it solves the original question, but nonetheless thanks for the pointer. It helped me with a related problem.