# Visual Studio: Configuration Manager missing

Tags: visual-studio, configurationmanager

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Team System 2008 Team Suite.

The "Configuration Manager" menu item is missing for me. I've assigned a keyboard shortcut to the Configuration Manager, but it doesn't have any effect (actually, it produces a "ding" sound).

How do I get the Configuration Manager to work for all projects?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The answer is: Make sure the following option is checked:

Tools ⇒ Options ⇒ Projects and Solutions ⇒ General ⇒ "Show advanced build configurations".

Comment: Is there a reason why it is checked for some solutions but not for every? Isn´t it a general option?

Comment: Yay for Google searches bringing up SO for a problem I had :D  +lvlup!

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2008 will only show the Configuration Manager if the solution node is visible in [Solution Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Other_tools). If you only have a single project, the solution will not show hence you can't see the Configuration Manager.

To solve this, make sure the following option is checked (in addition to Timwi's answer): menu *Tools* -> *Options* -> *Projects and Solutions* -> *General* -> *Always Show Solution*