# Difference between Bin/Debug and Bin/Release

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, visual-studio-express

I using a sql-server compact database within a c# winform project.

If I look at the files that make up the solution I can see a copy of the exe and the sdf file in both of the following folders:

1. `/bin/Debug/`
2. `/bin/Release/`

If I double-click and exe in 1. then it updates the sdf in 1. and likewise for the exe/sdf in 2.

When I open VS I assume I'm playing around with the files in 1. ?

When do the files in 2. get overwritten ?

When I publish the project using a Click-Once install which files are being used to create the `.application` file ?

**ADDITION**

The generic post above hasn't solved my problem but it has somewhat confused things further. Here is the *specific* scenario which I was hoping answers to the above would solve:

The development Solution folder is saved on a USB pen drive.
This Solution includes a database file.
I have publish to my home PC
I have published to my work PC.
I'm happy carrying the pen drive around and plugging in to either PC.
How do I set things up so that if I update the database only one version of the data exists?

I've changed the solution to Expert Settings and exposed the configuration manager - can this help?:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[What is the difference between Debug and Release in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367884/debug-release-difference)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa(v=vs.110).aspx

those are two diffrent configurations of the project.

and those are built into diffrent folders

the clikc once files are probably based on what is the current ACTIVE CONFIGURATION

Comment: +1 i've not amended the active configuration at all i.e it must be whatever the default is - how do I find the settings for thios configuration?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the project's configuration, if you're in debug mode you're using the debug one

Comment: but when I publish the project - without having amended any of the project's confirguration - which of these is being used; the version in Debug or the version in Release ?

Answer (score 1):

To see your active configuration:

Click on the "Build" tab, and then click "Configuration Manager".

You can also do this if you have a brand new recently installed  VS Express:

1. Tools ⇒ Settings ⇒ Expert Settings.
2. Tools ⇒ Option ⇒ check "show all settings" at bottom left corner.
3. Tools ⇒ Options ⇒ Projects and Solutions ⇒ General ⇒ "Show advanced
   build configurations".

Comment: Tools -> Settings -> Expert Settings. ... this just seems to switch the settings from Basic to Expert but doesn't help answer my question. I'm using VS Express so there is no Configuration Manager in the Build tab .. correcttion > there is no Build tab

Comment: Sorry. I use expert settings, so I didn't notice that. Show the expert settings as I've explained - then you'll see the "Build" tab. Even in the Express version.

Comment: I think you'll also see in one of the toolbars - a textbox with the current build. But maybe I added that later.

Comment: ok - changing to Expert settings has exposed the Build menu; but no option in that menu for Config Manager

Comment: At the bottom of the Project menu is an option for "<name of project>Properties ..." - maybe that is what I need. It has tabs down the left hand side for Publish / Build etc

Comment: Nope. What do you have in the "Build"? You're supposed to have: Build , Rebuild , Publish , and Configuration manager.

Comment: nope. Just three options: Build Solution / Rebuild Solution / Publish <name project>

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460459/visual-studio-configuration-manager-missing . You'll have to "check" the little box at the bottom left of the "options" menu ("show all settings") in order to see the "Projects and Solutions".

Comment: i wonder if it is because I've manually added a file App.config to this particular project ?

Comment: Now I have this menu let me add the full scenario to my OP as this menu might be a help