# How to build Debug AND Release and still get appropriate error messages?

Tags: visual-studio, build, error-reporting

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Team System 2008 Team Edition.

I want to be able to build my project and actually be told about all errors in the build. So far I have not found a way, so it must be pretty well hidden.

- The normal "Rebuild" command for a project, as well as the "Rebuild solution" command for a solution, rebuilds only the active configuration (Debug or Release), never both.
- Using the Batch Build dialog, as recommended in an answer to an [earlier question I posed about the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342107/visual-studio-how-to-rebuild-all), does not output any errors in the Error Window as I would have expected and just silently continues with the batch build instead of stopping as I would have expected. I had a compile error in my code for weeks without noticing because of this!

How do I get Visual Studio to build both configurations (if both compile) AND output error messages (if either one doesn't compile)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (at least not in VS 2008, any edition).